# not able to show drop down content on the click of list item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on left sidebar on my HTML page. My left sidebar has few texts which if we click then they should drop down and show few other texts:

Here is my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g2ahx6nq/40/

I have these below texts:

- OUR DNA
- PROGRAMS
- RESEARCH
- STORIES

So If I click any of the above texts on my left side bar it should drop down and show other texts belonging to them. Technically it should be like this image: https://s3.postimg.org/gbxn8hkf7/home1.png

As you can see in the left sidebar (in the above image), expanded versions of each of the above texts. I have to match the color and font as it is. Below is my HTML code for left bar navigation but somehow my click is not working at all and also not able to match the font and size as well. I am also missing the drop down arrow as well.

```
<div id="leftBar">
    <br />

    <svg id="clippedImg" width="0" height="0">
        <clipPath id="clipPolygon">
            <polygon points="1 100%,131 100%,130 0,0 0">
            </polygon>
        </clipPath>
    </svg>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#">OUR DNA</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-content">
                    <li><a href="#"><i>RISK</i></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#">PROGRAMS</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-content">
                    <li><a href="#"><i>PROFESSIONAL</i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i>ADVENTURE SPORT</i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i>ENTERTAINMENT</i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i>COLLEGIATE</i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i>INDIVIDUAL</i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i>COMMERCIAL</i></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#">RESEARCH</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-content">
                    <li><a href="#"><i>CORPORATE SURVEY</i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i>INDIVIDUAL SURVEY</i></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#">STORIES</a>
            </li>               
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

And this is my CSS:

```
nav ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

nav ul li {
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  display: block;
  width: 80px;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  background: #00648C;
}

ul.dropdown-content {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
```

What is wrorng I am doing by which my click is not working? And how can we match the font, color as well?

Comment: not sure, but everytime I try to inspect the list item, I get the top element and <img> as result. Maybe they are on top of it, so you are not actualy clicking the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**

Try this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jgf90mh9/18/

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".dropdown a").click(function(){
        $(this).closest('.dropdown').find('.dropdown-content').slideToggle(200);
        $(this).closest('.dropdown').siblings('.dropdown').find('.dropdown-content').slideUp(200);
    });
 });
```

Comment: Thanks yeah now it looks better.. Also how can we match the styling? If you compare to image in my question, it doesnt look like that.. Is there any way we can match that? I am still new to CSS designing so still learning. I think its mostly related to font size and font I believe and we need some arrow as well for drop down.

Comment: @david - yeah, for matching the design to the attached image you have to  set the font-family of your body tag according to your design (.psd or AI) file and you can use font-awesome library or images from your design for the arrows

Comment: sure got it .. can you help me understand how can I use font awesome for arrows here. I am already using font awesome in that same jsfiddle for other purpose.. can you help me in your same jsfiddle on how I can use arrows for drop down purpose.

Comment: thanks for the updated jsfiddle.. I can see the arrows now.. let me understand that first and see how it is working.

Comment: I have one quick question. If you look at my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g2ahx6nq/40/) as in the question I have, you will see on the top left bar there is a transparent image in the background and then on top of that I have texts on them. Right? In your [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jgf90mh9/) my top left bar is all black somehow? Any thoughts? I believe that transparent image is hiding behind that black?

Comment: @david - set `#leftbar` background-color to transparent `rgba(0,0,0,.57)`. see the updated fiddle above.

Comment: aahh.. cool got it.. one last question.. on my top left bar I have `LogIn` , `SignUp`, `Facebook, Instagram and Twitter` text and logo. In your jsfiddle it is getting shown on black portion of top left bar. In my jsfiddle it is just above that divider line and it is on transparent image? Correct.. I have tried few things to fix that but I am not able to. Any idea why it is going down?

Comment: fixed. set `top: -60px` to `above` class. See updated fiddle above.

Answer (score 1):

Try giving the nav ul selector in the css a position and z-index,   the 'top' element and img are on top of the list so you are not actualy clicking the list items.

css:

```
nav ul {
z-index:10;
position:absolute;
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
```

}

I haven't fixed the style problems with the list though ;)

Update: also try to add this

```
nav{
    height:auto;
}
```

and change this position to relative

```
ul.dropdown-content {
    position: relative; //was absolute
    display: none;
}
```

Edit: additional changes made

```
.dropdown-content li a{
    font-size:11px;
}
*{
    box-sizing:border-box; //using this on all elements, element size wont change when you set borders. giving a 2px border to a 150px div, the div will remain 150px. Same goes for paddings.
}
nav ul li {
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    width:100%; //makes sure the hover effect is the same width with all Li's
}
nav ul li a{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between; //spreads the li's text and arrow, arrows on 1 line
}
#leftBar {
    background-color: #030303;
    box-shadow: 2.996px 0.157px 7.65px 1.35px rgba(40, 40, 41, 0.25);
    border-right: solid #EF7440;
    border-right-width: 4px;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 2278px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 150px;  //gives more space for the arrow next to text.
}
```

Comment: It's not actually working when I click them. If I click them, it is showing on top of other texts. How can we make sure that if we click them it should slide down and show properly? And yeah styling I need some help as well. Still learning with css stuff so little bit new here.

Comment: Ive made 2 other changes in the css that might help you, edited the answer. Don't have time to fix the whole style thing though

Comment: yeah now it works much better but yeah styling thing is litte bit off here.. I will try to do on my own.. If you have time to help me out then it will be of great help. As still I am learning so it will be great experience.

Comment: @MaartenKuijper cool got it.. Also what is the best way to figure out the font so that I can exactly match with how it is getting shown on that image?

Comment: have your checked out google fonts yet?  you can put multiple fonts in 1 link like this: <link href='**https://fonts.googleapis.com/css**?family=PT+Sans|Arsenal|Yanone+Kaffeesatz|Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>.  then put it in your <head>

Comment: ok but how do we know which font is there on that image so that I can use that font and font size on my left sidebar?

Answer (score 0):

Because of `z-index: 2` you've set in `#clipimgA1` make your image overlap `#leftBar` div. You can not interact with `#leftBar` now since it is underneath of `#clipimgA1` although you still can see it due to `opacity: 0.5` you have set in `#clipimgA1`. I commented `z-index: 2; opacity: 0.5` in `#clipimgA1` and it now works as expected

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".dropdown").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this).children(".dropdown-content");
        $(".dropdown-content:visible").not($this).slideToggle(200); //Close submenu already opened
        $this.slideToggle(200); //Open the new submenu
    });
});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0px;
}

body {
    margin: 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

p,
span,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
td,
div,
ul,
li {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
}

.login {
    position: relative;
 top: -50px;
    z-index: 9999;
 color: white;
 text-decoration: none;
 padding: 0 10px;
 font-size: 13px;
}

.signup {
    position: relative;
 top: -50px;
    z-index: 9999;
 color: white;
 text-decoration: none;
 padding: 0;
 font-size: 13px;
}

.above {
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: row wrap;
 justify-content: flex-start;
 position: relative;
    z-index: 9999;
 top: -60px;
 padding: 0 5px;
}

.fa {
 color: white;
 margin: 5px;
}

img {
    /* Set max width to be 100% of the containing element */
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

body .company-bio p {
    font-family: 'agenda';
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    letter-spacing: .18em;
    font-family: 'agenda';
    font-weight: 400;
    color: rgb(254, 254, 255);
}

div.company-bio {}

body .company-bio {
 position: relative;
 top: -42px;
    padding-top: 40px;
    margin-left: 131px;
    /*Added Just now */
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    max-width: 100%;
    background: url("https://s30.postimg.org/l04wudgs1/grey-bar.png");
    padding-left: 140px;
    padding-right: 155px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: "Adelle PE";
}

.top h1 {
    color: #f86d2c;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 37px;
}

.top p {
    color: white !important;
    background-color: black;
}

.mission-statements .programs {
    position: relative;
    top: 60px;
    width: 300px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 4px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 19px;
    border-color: #EF7440;
    padding: 25px;
    margin: 25px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-shadow: 1.5px 2.598px 7.65px rgba(40, 40, 41, 0.16);
    font-family: "adelle regular";
    color: rgb(40, 40, 41);
    line-height: 1.979;
}

.top h4 {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: "ITC Avant Garde Gothic";
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 1.792;
    text-align: left;
    -moz-transform: matrix( 1.65479981820633, 0, 0, 1.66565153423699, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: matrix( 1.65479981820633, 0, 0, 1.66565153423699, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: matrix( 1.65479981820633, 0, 0, 1.66565153423699, 0, 0);
    position: absolute;
    left: 684.247px;
    top: 280.77px;
}

.top h2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 320px;
    left: 450px;
    letter-spacing: .3em;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-family: "Avant Garde", Avantgarde, "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 1.6;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0px 3px 6.37px rgba(40, 40, 41, 0.004);
}

body .northmanwild .title {
    /* background-image:url(assets/img/Uploads/insta-pics.png); */
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    padding-top: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 37px;
    margin-top: 0px !important;
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
    font-family: "Adelle PE";
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
    line-height: 1.979;
    text-align: center;
    /*text-shadow: 1.5px 2.598px 7.65px rgba(40, 40, 41, 0.5);
opacity: 100%;
fill: 57%;
*/
}

div.leftBar-bottom {
    background-image: url("https://s17.postimg.org/yvv4w2gmn/nav-background.png");
    float: left;
}

div.northmanwild {
    margin-top: -2px;
    width: 90.1%;
    float: right;
    opacity: 0.8;
    margin-bottom: -7px;
}

body .footer {
    width: 90.3%;
    float: right;
    color: rgb(40, 40, 41);
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    font-weight: normal;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url(assets/img/Uploads/footer-bg.png);
}


/*FIGURE OUT PROBLEM WITH MISSION STATEMENTS*/

body .mission-statements {
    margin-left: 131px;
    padding-bottom: 130px;
    padding-left: 45px;
    padding-right: 45px;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url(assets/img/Uploads/bg-trees.png);
}

body .mission-statements .why {
    padding-top: 40px;
    font-family: "Avant Garde", Avantgarde, "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    padding-left: 40px;
    position: relative;
    left: -40px;
    top: 30px;
}

body .mission-statements .how {
    padding-top: 40px;
    font-family: "Avant Garde", Avantgarde, "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-right: 40px;
}

body .mission-statements .what {
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    padding-left: 40px;
    font-family: "Avant Garde", Avantgarde, "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    left: -40px;
    top: 30px;
}

body .mission-statements .why pre {
    padding-left: 40px;
}

body .mission-statements .how {
    margin-top: 0px !important;
    padding-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}


/*.top .imgB1
{
  position: relative;
  top: -225px;
}

*/

.top {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-bottom: -7px;
}

.imgA1 {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.clippedmain {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#clippedImg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}

#clipimgA1 {
    /*Chrome,Safari*/
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(1px 100%, 131px 100%, 130px 0px, 0px 0px);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    /*z-index: 2;
    opacity: 0.5;*/
}


/*Firefox*/

clip-path: url("#clipPolygon");

/* iOS support inline encoded svg file*/

-webkit-mask: url(data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8;base64,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) no-repeat;

}
.imgB1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: -65px;
    left: 70px;
}
.footer .footer-section1 {
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
}
.footer .footer-section2 .block-title {
    position: relative;
    width: 338px;
    left: -140px;
    font-size: 16px !important;
    font-family: "AvantGarde";
    color: rgb(40, 40, 41);
    /* font-style: italic; */
    
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
}
.footer .footer-section2 .block-content {
    font-style: italic;
    line-height: 1.52;
    top: 18px;
    left: 52px;
    position: relative;
}
.footer .footer-section3 .block-content {
    position: relative;
    line-height: 1.52;
    left: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    top: 15px;
    font-style: italic;
}
.footer .footer-section3 .block-title {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
    width: 60%;
    left: 14px;
    position: relative;
}
.footer .footer-section1 .block-content {
    position: relative;
    line-height: 1.52;
    top: 67px;
    left: 125px;
    font-style: italic;
}
.footer .footer-section2 {
    position: relative;
    left: -89px;
}
.footer .footer-section2 {
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
}
.footer .footer-section3 {
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
}
.scroll-down {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in 3s;
    transition: all .5s ease-in 3s;
}
.scroll-down {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 28px;
    left: 55%;
    margin-left: -16px;
    display: block;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    background-size: 14px auto;
    border-radius: 50%;
    z-index: 2;
    -webkit-animation: bounce 2s infinite 2s;
    animation: bounce 2s infinite 2s;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in;
    transition: all .2s ease-in;
}
.scroll-down:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(50% - 8px);
    left: calc(50% - 6px);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    display: block;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    content: "";
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-width: 0px 0 2px 2px;
}
section.ok {
    position: relative;
    top: 2000px;
}
.copy-rights {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: "Avant Garde", Avantgarde, "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    top: 48px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    color: rgb(40, 40, 41);
    font-style: italic;
    -moz-transform: matrix( 0.99963252426166, 0, 0, 0.99882633931212, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: matrix( 0.99963252426166, 0, 0, 0.99882633931212, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: matrix( 0.99963252426166, 0, 0, 0.99882633931212, 0, 0);
    font-style: normal;
}
#leftBar {
    /*background-color: #030303;*/
    box-shadow: 2.996px 0.157px 7.65px 1.35px rgba(40, 40, 41, 0.25);
    border-right: solid #EF7440;
    border-right-width: 4px;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 2278px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 131px;
    /*Commented today */
    /* opacity: 0.5;  */
}

/*

#holder {
  width: 700px;
   margin-left: 263px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
  position: fixed;

}

*/
@font-face {
    font-family: BEBAS;
    src: url("http://webdesigncove.com/fonts/BEBAS___.ttf")
}
h1.logo {
    font-size: 26px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    letter-spacing: -3px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
h1.postTitle {
    font-family: BEBAS, Helvetica, Verdana, Sans-Serif;
}
p {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    letter-spacing: .28em;
    line-height: 1.45em;
}
#navigation {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
}
#navigation li {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
#navigation a:link {
    font-family: "ITC Avant Garde Gothic";
    font-size: 15px;
    font-style: normal;
}
#navigation a:visited {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
#navigation a:hover {
    color: #FE5B1F;
}
.copy-right-text {
    font: Bold 12px 'Open Sans';
    color: #ffffff;
    padding-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
nav ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

nav ul li {
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  display: block;
  width: 80px;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  background: #00648C;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul.dropdown-content {
  /*position: absolute;*/
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="top">
    <img id="clipimgA1" class="clippedmain" src="https://s28.postimg.org/tkwg9tmdp/homepage-image-1.png" alt="img">
    <img class="imgA1" src="https://s28.postimg.org/tkwg9tmdp/homepage-image-1.png">
</div>

 <div id="leftBar">
  <br />

  <svg id="clippedImg" width="0" height="0">
   <clipPath id="clipPolygon">
    <polygon points="1 100%,131 100%,130 0,0 0">
    </polygon>
   </clipPath>      
  </svg>
    
  <nav>
   <ul>
    <li class="dropdown">
     <a href="#">OUR DNA</a>
     <ul class="dropdown-content">
      <li><a href="#"><i>RISK</i></a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
        
    <li class="dropdown">
     <a href="#">PROGRAMS</a>
     <ul class="dropdown-content">
      <li><a href="#"><i>PROFESSIONAL</i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i>ADVENTURE SPORT</i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i>ENTERTAINMENT</i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i>COLLEGIATE</i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i>INDIVIDUAL</i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i>COMMERCIAL</i></a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
        
    <li class="dropdown">
     <a href="#">RESEARCH</a>
     <ul class="dropdown-content">
      <li><a href="#"><i>CORPORATE SURVEY</i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i>INDIVIDUAL SURVEY</i></a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
        
    <li class="dropdown">
     <a href="#">STORIES</a>
    </li>    
   </ul>
  </nav>
 </div>


<ul class="above">
    <li><i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-twitter-square"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></li>
</ul>
<a class="login" href="#">Log In&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|</a>
<a class="signup" href="#">Sign Up</a>
<div class="leftBar-bottom">

</div>

<!-- End Side bar div-->
<div class="company-bio">
    <p align="center" style="font-family: Adelle PE">Hello World </p>
    <p align="center" style="font-family: Adelle PE">Nice Text! </p>
    <p align="center">Hello David</p>
</div>
```

Updated: I've commented `position: absolute` from

```
ul.dropdown-content {
  /*position: absolute;*/
  display: none;
}
```

and it instantly achieves some effects you wanted

Comment: It's not actually working when I click them. If I click them, it is showing on top of other texts. How can we make sure that if we click them it should slide down and show properly? And for styling I need some help as well. Still learning with css stuff so little bit new here.

Comment: Like you said It appears and is showing on top of other texts, so It's working, you can interact with it. You need to style it a bit more to make it look beautiful

Comment: yeah that is where I am stuck now as I am still a beginner so not sure how we can fix this.